Hide the seconds from angular datepicker input
I am using angular datepicker and i want to hide the seconds from the input box
<mat-form-field class="input-ff transparent-bg no-warning underline-prefix">
        <mat-label >{{ 'EstimatedArrivalTime' | translate }}</mat-label>
        <mat-icon matPrefix class="fill-underline">info</mat-icon>

        <input matInput [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="formattedEDTA"
                          (dateChange)="dateChanged($event)"
                           />
        <mat-hint style="color: black;">DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm</mat-hint>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <ngx-mat-datetime-picker #picker [showSpinners]="true" [showSeconds]="false"
                          [pickerType]="'calendar'" [startView]="'month'" [dateFormat]="'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'"
                          [stepHour]="1">
        </ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
</mat-form-field>

<span style="color: red;">- {{formattedEDTA}} -</span>

and then in my ts
private _selectedData;
formattedEDTA: string;

 set selectedData(value: any) {
        this_selectedData= value;
        this.formattedEDTA = this.formatDate(value.EDTA);
    }

    get selectedData(): any {
        return this._selectedData;
    }

formatDate(date: Date | moment.Moment): string {
        return moment(date).isValid() ? moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm') : '';
    }
dateChanged(event: any): void {
        if (event.value) {
            this._selectedData.EDTA = event.value;
            this.formattedEDTA = this.formatDate(event.value);
        }
    }

initially it is not showing any value in the input but in the span value is there for formattedEDTA
27/06/2024 23:37

and when i change the date it shows the 19/06/2024, 00:00:00 in dateinput but in span it shows 19/06/2024 00:00
Am i missing something? it should the correct date in input date box as well
Update 1
i tried in my module like this
export const CUSTOM_DATE_FORMATS: NgxMatDateFormats = {
    parse: {
        dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
    },
    display: {
        dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
        monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
        dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
        monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
    },
};

and in my providers
providers: [
        MatIconRegistry,
        DatePipe,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        NgxMatDatetimePickerModule,
        {
            provide: LOCALE_ID,
            useValue: 'sv',
        },
        {
            provide: LOCALE_ID,
            useValue: 'nb',
        },
        {
            provide: LOCALE_ID,
            useValue: 'en',
        },
        { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB' },
        { provide: NGX_MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: CUSTOM_DATE_FORMATS }
    ]

but now this is shwing


Please add a working stackblitz example

Looks like there is some code that is affecting this behavior and is not presented in the question. Creating a custom adapter CUSTOM_DATE_FORMATS and setting the display dateInput format as presented in Update 1 should be sufficient to hide the seconds  and keep the minutes displayed

I reproduced your example on a stackblitz but i'm not able to reproduce your behaviior:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/demo-ngx-mat-datetime-picker-angular10-xgvxsf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts
